# Easy implementation of UTM Tracking via email

Tags: email, google-analytics, web-analytics, urchin

So here is the deal:

I understand UTM tracking very well but am wondering anyones experience with implementation in scenarios where a business has many different email notifications that are sent out on behalf of the website.

My question is simple but the goal is to relay some the needed information to our CTO. Obviously if you use Googles URL builder and were aiming at implementing the UTM manually the tasks required are very straightforward.

However what I am wondering is what would you do in a situation where you have 40 different emails that you want tracked using UTM?

How would one go about this dynamically instead of statically one by one.

Would you just attach the parameters in the email and populate them dynamically?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could use a service like [Terminus](http://term.li/1pkmEjI). It helps you build URLs in bulk and remembers your UTM parameters. It's not free, though.

Disclaimer: I'm the founder of Terminus.